# Do I need to use HTML entities when storing data in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I need to store special characters and symbols into mysql database. So either I can store it as it is like 'ü' or convert it to html code such as '&uuml;'

I am not sure which would be better.

Also I am having symbols like '♥', '„' .

Please suggest which one is better? Also suggest if there is any alternative method.

Thanks.

Comment: I took the liberty of changing your title a bit - your title was fine, but this way, it's easier to find for future similar questions. (I just searched and realized there is no easy-to-find duplicate of this.)

Comment: That depends on the charset the column is using where you store the HTML. Normally you should use a charset that covers all characters (so none are "special") and your data can be stored in a normalized form and does not contain any special encoding next to the bare charset encoding which every text-field in a database has anyway.

Comment: @Pekka That's fine. If it's helpful to other this way, I must thank you.

Comment: @hakre That is right. I have to set "accept-charset" attribute of form tag to "ISO-8859-1" to get all the characters as it is in the database. Can you shed some light on that is that good practice or not?

Comment: `ISO-8859-1` or sometimes called `LATIN-1` is the character set used by the browser to send the text over the wire. If you then store that raw data into the database and this works, it means that the database connection is also using `ISO-8859-1` and the column in the data you store the text into is able to store a text in it's own column charset that covers the same characters (could be `ISO-8859-1` as well or something else like `UTF-8`). `ISO-8859-1` is very often used as standard charset, so this is fine as long as all characters you need are covered by it.

Comment: ok. Thanks for clarification. So in short one should always go with a character set which includes all the characters needed and maintain it through out all the way, including html page encoding, database connection encoding, database column encoding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML entities have been introduced years ago to transport character information over the wire when transportation was not binary safe and for the case that the user-agent (browser) did not support the charset encoding of the transport-layer or server.

As a HTML entity contains only very basic characters (`&`, `;`, `a-z` and `0-9`) and those characters have the same binary encoding in most character sets, this is and was very safe from those side-effects.

However when you store something in the database, you don't have these issues because you're normally in control and you know what and how you can store text into the database.

For example, if you allow Unicode for text inside the database, you can store all characters, none is actually special. Note that you need to know your database here, there are some technical details you can run into. Like you don't know the charset encoding for your database connection so you can't exactly tell your database which text you want to store in there.  But generally, you just store the text and retrieve it later. Nothing special to deal with.

In fact there are downsides when you use HTML entities instead of the plain character:

- HTML entities consume more space: `&uuml;` is much larger than `ü` in LATIN-1, UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32.
- HTML entities need further processing. They need to be created, and when read, they need to be parsed. Imagine you need to search for a specific text in your database, or any other action would need additional handling. That's just overhead.

The real fun starts when you mix both concepts. You come to a place you really don't want to go into. So just don't do it because you ain't gonna need it.

Comment: This is 5 years old but I want to testify to the "real fun" mentioned in the last paragraph. We have a MySql database that has plenty of tables that have fields with `latin1` AND fields with `utf-8` collations. We have stored both special characters (mostly registered and trade mark) and html entities (and in some cases double-encoded html entities, i.e. `&amp;reg;`) in the database. Boys and girls, don't go down this road. Make smart decisions when it comes on how to store characters in your database and stick with it. When you pull the data out, THEN you can modify it however you need.

Answer (score 5):

Leave your data raw in the database.  Don't use HTML entities for these until you need them for HTML.  You never know when you may want to use your data elsewhere, not on a web page.

Comment: +1, but `htmlentities` is not even necessary when outputting HTML - a `htmlspecialchars()` will do to prevent XSS. `htmlentities` should *never* be necessary in a properly configured environment

Comment: @Pekka, I wasn't suggesting using the function, I was referring to the entities themselves.  Yes, `htmlspecialchars()` is the preferred method for actually outputting the data.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would mirror the other contributors, **don't convert the special entities** when saving them to your database.

**Some reasons against conversion:**

- [K.I.S.S principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) (my biggest reason not to do it)
- most entities will end up consuming more space then prior to being converted
- loose the ability to search for the entities `ü` in a word, would be `[word]+ü+[/word]`, and you would have to do a string comparison of the html equivalent of `ü` => `[word]+&uuml;+[/word]`.
- your ouput may change from HTML to say an API for mobile, etc which makes conversion very unnecessary.
- need to convert on input of data, and on output (again if your output changes from plain HTML to something else).